# Is there a replacement for an asterisk in R?

Tags: r, subset, multiple-columns

I am trying to subset on Diagnostic Codes and I don't want to type in every code.  For example, I want to subset on Diabetes ICD-9 Code- so there's 250.00, 250.01, 250.02, etc in 30 different Dx Columns. I tried the hat but that doesn't work either. Also tried grepl(DxDF, "^250.") and str_subset(DxDF4, "^250")

This doesn't work: ***Note there are asterisks after the period, but for some reason it's not coming through when publishing this question

```
        Diabetes <- DxDF[ DxDF$DX1 == "250.*" | DxDF$DX2 == "250.*" | DxDF$DX3 == "250.*" | DxDF$DX4 == "250.*" | DxDF$DX5 == "250.*" | DxDF$DX6 == "250.*" | 
                      DxDF$DX7 == "250.*" | DxDF$DX8 == "250.*" | DxDF$DX9 == "250.*" | DxDF$DX10 == "250.*" | DxDF$DX11 == "250.*" | DxDF$DX12 == "250.*" | 
                      DxDF$DX13 == "250.*" | DxDF$DX14 == "250.*" | DxDF$DX15 == "250.*" | DxDF$DX16 == "250.*" | DxDF$DX17 == "250.*" | DxDF$DX18 == "250.*" |
                      DxDF$DX19 == "250.*" | DxDF$DX20 == "250.*" | DxDF$DX21 == "250.*" | DxDF$DX22 == "250.*" | DxDF$DX23 == "250.*" | DxDF$DX24 == "250.*" | 
                      DxDF$DX25 == "250.*" | DxDF$DX26 == "250.*" | DxDF$DX27 == "250.*" | DxDF$DX28 == "250.*" | DxDF$DX29 == "250.*" | DxDF$DX30 == "250.*" ,]
```

And this doesn't work:

```
        Diabetes <- DxDF[ DxDF$DX1 == "^250." | DxDF$DX2 == "^250." | DxDF$DX3 == "^250." | DxDF$DX4 == "^250." | DxDF$DX5 == "^250." | DxDF$DX6 == "^250." | 
                      DxDF$DX7 == "250." | DxDF$DX8 == "^250." | DxDF$DX9 == "^250." | DxDF$DX10 == "^250." | DxDF$DX11 == "^250." | DxDF$DX12 == "^250." | 
                      DxDF$DX13 == "^250." | DxDF$DX14 == "^250." | DxDF$DX15 == "^250." | DxDF$DX16 == "^250." | DxDF$DX17 == "^250." | DxDF$DX18 == "^250." |
                      DxDF$DX19 == "^250." | DxDF$DX20 == "^250." | DxDF$DX21 == "^250." | DxDF$DX22 == "^250." | DxDF$DX23 == "^250." | DxDF$DX24 == "^250." | 
                      DxDF$DX25 == "^250." | DxDF$DX26 == "^250." | DxDF$DX27 == "^250." | DxDF$DX28 == "^250." | DxDF$DX29 == "^250." | DxDF$DX30 == "^250." ,]
```

Results of `dput(head(DxDF, 5))` (20 was too big and MRN and Pt_Account_Number columns have been replaced with ## to deID)

```r
        structure(list(MRN = c("####", "####", "####", "####", 
"####"), Pt_Account_Number = c("####", "####", 
"####", "####", "####"), DX1 = c("J98.6", 
"I13.0", "A41.9", "D57.00", "I34.0"), DX1_DESC = c("J98.6-DISORDERS OF DIAPHRAGM-J98.6", 
"I13.0-HTN HRT CKD W/HF STAGE 1-4/UNS CKD-I13.0", "A41.9-SEPSIS UNSPECIFIED ORGANISM-A41.9", 
"D57.00-HB-SS DISEASE WITH CRISIS UNS-D57.00", "I34.0-NONRHEUMATIC MITRAL INSUFFICIENCY-I34.0"
), DX2 = c("I50.33", "J96.01", "I50.23", "I50.33", "I50.23"), 
    DX2_DESC = c("I50.33-ACUTE ON CHRONIC DIASTOLIC CHF-I50.33", 
    "J96.01-ACUTE RESPIRATORY FAIL W/HYPOXIA-J96.01", "I50.23-ACUTE CHRON SYSTOLIC HEART FAILURE-I50.23", 
    "I50.33-ACUTE ON CHRONIC DIASTOLIC CHF-I50.33", "I50.23-ACUTE CHRON SYSTOLIC HEART FAILURE-I50.23"
    ), DX3 = c("Z68.41", "I50.21", "J18.9", "M87.9", "J96.01"
    ), DX3_DESC = c("Z68.41-BODY MASS INDEX 40.0-44.9 ADULT-Z68.41", 
    "I50.21-ACUTE SYSTOLIC HEART FAILURE-I50.21", "J18.9-PNEUMONIA UNSPECIFIED ORGANISM-J18.9", 
    "M87.9-OSTEONECROSIS UNSPECIFIED-M87.9", "J96.01-ACUTE RESPIRATORY FAIL W/HYPOXIA-J96.01"
    ), DX4 = c("J93.82", "F05.", "I63.519", "E87.0", "J95.2"), 
    DX4_DESC = c("J93.82-OTHER AIR LEAK-J93.82", "F05.-DELIRIUM DUE KNOWN PHYSIOLOG COND-F05.", 
    "I63.519-CEREB INFARCT UNS OCCL/STEN UNS MCA-I63.519", "E87.0-HYPEROSMOLALITY AND HYPERNATREMIA-E87.0", 
    "J95.2-AC PULM INSUFF FLW NONTHORACIC SURG-J95.2"), DX5 = c("I97.89", 
    "Z68.41", "E87.1", "J81.1", "R57.0"), DX5_DESC = c("I97.89-OTH POSTPROC COMP D/O CIRC SYS NEC-I97.89", 
    "Z68.41-BODY MASS INDEX 40.0-44.9 ADULT-Z68.41", "E87.1-HYPO-OSMOLALITY AND HYPONATREMIA-E87.1", 
    "J81.1-CHRONIC PULMONARY EDEMA-J81.1", "R57.0-CARDIOGENIC SHOCK-R57.0"
    ), DX6 = c("K44.9", "E78.5", "I42.9", "I13.0", "E43."), DX6_DESC = c("K44.9-DIAPH HERNIA W/O OBST/GANGRENE-K44.9", 
    "E78.5-HYPERLIPIDEMIA UNSPECIFIED-E78.5", "I42.9-CARDIOMYOPATHY UNSPECIFIED-I42.9", 
    "I13.0-HTN HRT CKD W/HF STAGE 1-4/UNS CKD-I13.0", "E43.-UNS SEVERE PROTEIN-CALORIE MLNUTRIT-E43."
    ), DX7 = c("I25.10", "E11.51", "N39.0", "I66.9", "J95.1"), 
    DX7_DESC = c("I25.10-ASHD NATIVE CA W/O ANGINA PECTORIS-I25.10", 
    "E11.51-TYPE 2 DM DIAB P ANGIOPATH NO GNGRN-E11.51", "N39.0-UTI SITE NOT SPECIFIED-N39.0", 
    "I66.9-OCCLUSION & STENOS UNS CEREBRAL ART-I66.9", "J95.1-ACUTE PULM INSUFF FOLLOW THOR SURG-J95.1"
    ), DX8 = c("E87.6", "E11.22", "I48.1", "I27.20", "I13.0"), 
    DX8_DESC = c("E87.6-HYPOKALEMIA-E87.6", "E11.22-TYPE 2 DM W/DIABETIC CKD-E11.22", 
    "I48.1-PERSISTENT ATRIAL FIBRILLATION-I48.1", "I27.20-PULMONARY HYPERTENSION UNSPECIFIED-I27.20", 
    "I13.0-HTN HRT CKD W/HF STAGE 1-4/UNS CKD-I13.0"), DX9 = c("D50.8", 
    "E66.9", "G82.20", "I07.1", "N17.9"), DX9_DESC = c("D50.8-OTHER IRON DEFICIENCY ANEMIAS-D50.8", 
    "E66.9-OBESITY UNSPECIFIED-E66.9", "G82.20-PARAPLEGIA UNSPECIFIED-G82.20", 
    "I07.1-RHEUMATIC TRICUSPID INSUFFICIENCY-I07.1", "N17.9-ACUTE KIDNEY FAILURE UNSPECIFIED-N17.9"
    ), DX10 = c("J44.9", "F41.9", "G93.40", "E87.5", "Z68.1"), 
    DX10_DESC = c("J44.9-COPD UNSPECIFIED-J44.9", "F41.9-ANXIETY DISORDER UNSPECIFIED-F41.9", 
    "G93.40-ENCEPHALOPATHY UNSPECIFIED-G93.40", "E87.5-HYPERKALEMIA-E87.5", 
    "Z68.1-BODY MASS INDEX 19/LESS ADULT-Z68.1"), DX11 = c("E78.5", 
    "F32.9", "R18.8", "N18.3", "R64."), DX11_DESC = c("E78.5-HYPERLIPIDEMIA UNSPECIFIED-E78.5", 
    "F32.9-MAJ DEPRESS D/O SINGLE EPIS UNS-F32.9", "R18.8-OTHER ASCITES-R18.8", 
    "N18.3-CKD STAGE 3 MODERATE-N18.3", "R64.-CACHEXIA-R64."), 
    DX12 = c("I11.0", "N18.3", "E87.5", "E55.9", "A31.0"), DX12_DESC = c("I11.0-HTN HEART DISEASE W/HEART FAIL-I11.0", 
    "N18.3-CKD STAGE 3 MODERATE-N18.3", "E87.5-HYPERKALEMIA-E87.5", 
    "E55.9-VITAMIN D DEFICIENCY UNSPECIFIED-E55.9", "A31.0-PULMONARY MYCOBACTERIAL INFECTION-A31.0"
    ), DX13 = c("E11.51", "K59.00", "I11.0", "H36.", "D62."), 
    DX13_DESC = c("E11.51-TYPE 2 DM DIAB P ANGIOPATH NO GNGRN-E11.51", 
    "K59.00-CONSTIPATION UNSPECIFIED-K59.00", "I11.0-HTN HEART DISEASE W/HEART FAIL-I11.0", 
    "H36.-RETINAL DISORDERS DZ CLASS ELSW-H36.", "D62.-ACUTE POSTHEMORRHAGIC ANEMIA-D62."
    ), DX14 = c("G47.33", "J44.9", "N40.1", "R11.2", "G72.81"
    ), DX14_DESC = c("G47.33-OBSTRUCTIVE SLEEP APNEA-G47.33", 
    "J44.9-COPD UNSPECIFIED-J44.9", "N40.1-BENIGN PROSTATIC HYPERPLASIA W/LUTS-N40.1", 
    "R11.2-NAUSEA WITH VOMITING UNSPECIFIED-R11.2", "G72.81-CRITICAL ILLNESS MYOPATHY-G72.81"
    ), DX15 = c("E66.01", "Z95.1", "K76.1", "E86.0", "I47.2"), 
    DX15_DESC = c("E66.01-MORBID SEVERE OBES D/T EXCESS CAL-E66.01", 
    "Z95.1-PRESENCE AORTOCORONARY BYPASS GRAFT-Z95.1", "K76.1-CHRONIC PASSIVE CONGESTION OF LIVER-K76.1", 
    "E86.0-DEHYDRATION-E86.0", "I47.2-VENTRICULAR TACHYCARDIA-I47.2"
    ), DX16 = c("I48.0", "Z95.5", "Z79.01", "M79.605", "I42.0"
    ), DX16_DESC = c("I48.0-PAROXYSMAL ATRIAL FIBRILLATION-I48.0", 
    "Z95.5-PRESENCE COR ANGPLSTY IMPLANT GRAFT-Z95.5", "Z79.01-LONG TERM CURRNT USE ANTICOAGULANTS-Z79.01", 
    "M79.605-PAIN IN LEFT LEG-M79.605", "I42.0-DILATED CARDIOMYOPATHY-I42.0"
    ), DX17 = c("Z79.51", "Z66.", "Z74.01", "H25.13", "I42.9"
    ), DX17_DESC = c("Z79.51-LONG TERM USE INHALED STEROIDS-Z79.51", 
    "Z66.-DO NOT RESUSCITATE-Z66.", "Z74.01-BED CONFINEMENT STATUS-Z74.01", 
    "H25.13-AGE-REL NUCLEAR CATARACT BILAT-H25.13", "I42.9-CARDIOMYOPATHY UNSPECIFIED-I42.9"
    ), DX18 = c("Z79.82", "I25.10", "R33.8", "M19.079", "I48.3"
    ), DX18_DESC = c("Z79.82-LONG TERM CURRENT USE OF ASPIRIN-Z79.82", 
    "I25.10-ASHD NATIVE CA W/O ANGINA PECTORIS-I25.10", "R33.8-OTHER RETENTION OF URINE-R33.8", 
    "M19.079-PRIMARY OSTEOARTHRITIS UNS ANK FOOT-M19.079", "I48.3-TYPICAL ATRIAL FLUTTER-I48.3"
    ), DX19 = c("Z85.01", "Z79.4", "F03.90", "R09.1", "J95.89"
    ), DX19_DESC = c("Z85.01-PERS HX MALIG NEOPLASM ESOPHAGUS-Z85.01", 
    "Z79.4-LONG TERM CURRENT USE OF INSULIN-Z79.4", "F03.90-UNS DEMENT W/O BEHAVIORAL DIST-F03.90", 
    "R09.1-PLEURISY-R09.1", "J95.89-OTH POSTPROC COMP D/O RESP SYS NEC-J95.89"
    ), DX20 = c("Z89.512", "I42.9", "Z66.", "F14.11", "I25.10"
    ), DX20_DESC = c("Z89.512-ACQUIRED ABSENCE LEFT LEG BK-Z89.512", 
    "I42.9-CARDIOMYOPATHY UNSPECIFIED-I42.9", "Z66.-DO NOT RESUSCITATE-Z66.", 
    "F14.11-COCAINE ABUSE IN REMISSION-F14.11", "I25.10-ASHD NATIVE CA W/O ANGINA PECTORIS-I25.10"
    ), DX21 = c("Z95.5", "E83.42", "G93.89", "K59.03", "N18.3"
    ), DX21_DESC = c("Z95.5-PRESENCE COR ANGPLSTY IMPLANT GRAFT-Z95.5", 
    "E83.42-HYPOMAGNESEMIA-E83.42", "G93.89-OTHER SPECIFIED DISORDERS OF BRAIN-G93.89", 
    "K59.03-DRUG INDUCED CONSTIPATION-K59.03", "N18.3-CKD STAGE 3 MODERATE-N18.3"
    ), DX22 = c("Z98.84", "I27.20", "I46.2", "T40.2X5A", "I73.9"
    ), DX22_DESC = c("Z98.84-BARIATRIC SURGERY STATUS-Z98.84", 
    "I27.20-PULMONARY HYPERTENSION UNSPECIFIED-I27.20", "I46.2-CARD ARREST D/T UNDERLY CARD COND-I46.2", 
    "T40.2X5A-ADVERSE EFF OTH OPIOIDS INITIAL ENC-T40.2X5A", 
    "I73.9-PERIPHERAL VASCULAR DISEASE UNS-I73.9"), DX23 = c("Z99.81", 
    "Z82.49", "I50.82", "K21.9", "E78.5"), DX23_DESC = c("Z99.81-DEPENDENCE ON SUPPLEMENTAL OXYGEN-Z99.81", 
    "Z82.49-FAM HX ISCHEMIC HRT DZ OTH DZ CIRC-Z82.49", "I50.82-BIVENTRICULAR HEART FAILURE-I50.82", 
    "K21.9-GERD WITHOUT ESOPHAGITIS-K21.9", "E78.5-HYPERLIPIDEMIA UNSPECIFIED-E78.5"
    ), DX24 = c("Z82.49", "Z79.82", "N28.1", "H04.123", "K21.9"
    ), DX24_DESC = c("Z82.49-FAM HX ISCHEMIC HRT DZ OTH DZ CIRC-Z82.49", 
    "Z79.82-LONG TERM CURRENT USE OF ASPIRIN-Z79.82", "N28.1-CYST OF KIDNEY ACQUIRED-N28.1", 
    "H04.123-DRY EYE SYNDROME BIL LACRIML GLANDS-H04.123", "K21.9-GERD WITHOUT ESOPHAGITIS-K21.9"
    ), DX25 = c("G54.6", "Z88.3", "R29.715", "M75.02", "Z95.810"
    ), DX25_DESC = c("G54.6-PHANTOM LIMB SYNDROME WITH PAIN-G54.6", 
    "Z88.3-ALLERGY STATUS OTH ANTI-INF AGT STS-Z88.3", "R29.715-NIHSS SCORE 15-R29.715", 
    "M75.02-ADHESIVE CAPSULITIS LEFT SHOULDER-M75.02", "Z95.810-PRESENCE AUTO IMPLANT CARDIAC DEFIB-Z95.810"
    ), DX26 = c("G89.18", "N28.9", "R29.810", "M54.5", "I49.3"
    ), DX26_DESC = c("G89.18-OTHER ACUTE POSTPROCEDURAL PAIN-G89.18", 
    "N28.9-DISORDER KIDNEY AND URETER UNS-N28.9", "R29.810-FACIAL WEAKNESS-R29.810", 
    "M54.5-LOW BACK PAIN-M54.5", "I49.3-VENTRICULR PREMATURE DEPOLARIZATION-I49.3"
    ), DX27 = c("G89.29", "D63.8", "Z79.82", "Z86.711", "I95.9"
    ), DX27_DESC = c("G89.29-OTHER CHRONIC PAIN-G89.29", "D63.8-ANEMIA IN OTH CHRONIC DZ CLASS ELSW-D63.8", 
    "Z79.82-LONG TERM CURRENT USE OF ASPIRIN-Z79.82", "Z86.711-PERSONAL HISTORY PULMONARY EMBOLISM-Z86.711", 
    "I95.9-HYPOTENSION UNSPECIFIED-I95.9"), DX28 = c("M54.5", 
    "I70.203", "Z79.899", "Z88.5", "D69.6"), DX28_DESC = c("M54.5-LOW BACK PAIN-M54.5", 
    "I70.203-UNS ATHEROSCLR NATV ART EXT BIL LEG-I70.203", "Z79.899-OTH LONG TERM CURRENT DRUG THERAPY-Z79.899", 
    "Z88.5-ALLERGY STATUS NARCOTIC AGT STATUS-Z88.5", "D69.6-THROMBOCYTOPENIA UNSPECIFIED-D69.6"
    ), DX29 = c("F41.9", "Z89.421", "Z80.3", "Z90.49", "R13.10"
    ), DX29_DESC = c("F41.9-ANXIETY DISORDER UNSPECIFIED-F41.9", 
    "Z89.421-ACQUIRED ABSENCE OTHER RIGHT TOES-Z89.421", "Z80.3-FAMILY HX MALIG NEOPLASM OF BREAST-Z80.3", 
    "Z90.49-ACQ ABSENCE OTH PART DIGESTV TRACT-Z90.49", "R13.10-DYSPHAGIA UNSPECIFIED-R13.10"
    ), DX30 = c("Z87.891", "Z80.3", "Z82.0", "Z82.49", "E16.2"
    ), DX30_DESC = c("Z87.891-PERSONAL HISTORY NICOTINE DEPEND-Z87.891", 
    "Z80.3-FAMILY HX MALIG NEOPLASM OF BREAST-Z80.3", "Z82.0-FAM HX EPILEPSY OTH DZ NERV SYS-Z82.0", 
    "Z82.49-FAM HX ISCHEMIC HRT DZ OTH DZ CIRC-Z82.49", "E16.2-HYPOGLYCEMIA UNSPECIFIED-E16.2"
    )), row.names = c("6", "7", "12", "22", "25"), class = "data.frame")
```

All Dx Columns are class = Character

Comment: Can you post sample data? Please edit **the question** with the output of `dput(DxDF)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(DxDF, 20))`. Try to subset some columns only, there's no need to test the code in 30 columns, 5 or 6 will do.

Comment: Maybe `grepl("200\\.\\d*", x)` for every column `DX`. But note that the class of those columns is not clear, are they numeric?

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
## identify columns of interest
DXcols  <- grep("^DX[0-9]+", names(DxDF)) 
## detect 200.* codes in every column
has_diabetes <- apply(DxDF[, DXcols], 2, FUN=grepl, pattern="^250\\.")
## check for any TRUE values in each row
Diabetes <- apply(has_diabetes, 1, any)
```

There are of course various ways to do this.  You could define a function `diabetes_code <- function(x) substr(x,1,4)=="250."`, then `apply(DxDF[, DXcols, 2, FUN=diabetes_code)` ...

Looking at your pasted data, it looks like there's a letter code before most diagnoses, not sure why? If this occurs for the diabetes-related codes as well, you might not want to anchor your search pattern to the beginning of the string: `pattern="250\\."` or `pattern="^[A-Z]250\\."` might work better ...